# asp.net email validation regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I want to validate email in asp.net `RegularExpressionValidator` where email id is

- abc
- abc.def
- abc_def

I have tried

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]+([_]{0,1})|([.]{0,1})[0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

but the or condition doesn't work. It always fails for 2nd condition.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the second pattern inside a group and make it as optional.

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:[._][0-9a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rL8wP1/11)

Comment: @MayurMohite Please accept an answer that solves your problem by clicking the checkmark under the score.

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]+[._]?[0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

You can simply do this instead.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/31

For yours to work you can do

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:[_]{0,1})|(?:[.]{0,1}))[0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/32

Comment: @MayurMohite it is working as you can see from demo.You can try the first one as well

Comment: enjoy a cup of chai ☕  :]

Comment: @Jonny5 haha....... part of my daily routine...... ☕  with some regex talk !!!! when you come here :)